# How to change the name of a file to a primary key ID?

Tags: php, html, mysql, file

So I have a program that the user inputs text into a text box, and then that text is created into a file. Each time the submit button is pressed, the database creates a job and is given a jobID. I was wondering if there was anyway to make the name of the file the job_id.fasta instead of just calling it new.fasta. This way I am able to store more files! Thanks in advance. I will post the code of creating the file and storing it.

```
<form method="POST", action="/~cs4380sp15grp4/home/blast.php" class="form-inline">
<textarea id="BlastSearch" type="textarea" name="BlastSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Protein sequence in fasta format"></textarea>
<button id="run" type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span> Run BLAST</button>
</form>

<?php
    session_start();



    require_once '../secure/database.php';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    if($mysqli->connect_error){
            exit('CON Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }

    //Insert the values into the database

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


            $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];

            //create a new .fasta file and put the sequence the user wants to search for in that file
            $file = 'uploads/new.fasta';
            $current = $sequence;
            file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: I don't see an insert here but insert_id should do it, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php.

Comment: Thanks. How would I append that to the end of a directory? Like 'students/groups/home/'.$mysqli->insert_id.'.fasta'   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply insert record in database before new file creation and get job_id using `$mysqli->insert_id` to make the name of the file `job_id.fasta`

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '../secure/database.php';
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

if($mysqli->connect_error){
        exit('CON Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ' ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

//Insert the values into the database

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO `jobs` (`BlastSearch`) VALUES ('".$sequence."')";
        $mysqli->query($query);
        $job_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
        //create a new .fasta file and put the sequence the user wants to search for in that file
        $file = "uploads/".$job_id.".fasta";
        $current = $sequence;
        file_put_contents($file, $current);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming job_id is the automatically inserted ID, you could use `last_id` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php:

```
//Insert the values into the database

// Fictitious MySQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO search (keyword) VALUES ('mysearch')";
$last_id = "";

if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  $last_id = $mysqli->insert_id;
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
  die();
}
// End fictitious MySQL

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $sequence = $_POST['BlastSearch'];

  //create a new .fasta file and put the sequence the user wants to search for in that file
  $file = 'uploads/'.$last_id.'.fasta';  // < Use insert_id here.
  $current = $sequence;
  file_put_contents($file, $current);
```